# How to design for tableview reuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having some trouble designing with reusability in mind. In one part of my app I have a `UITableViewController` and in another I have a `UITableView`. Both of these should look the same and they use the same data. That's why I thought I should start using separate `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource` classes.

```
@interface RestaurantsTableSource : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMResults *restaurants;

@end
```

In my `UIViewController` I'd then have a strong reference to this:

```
@interface RestaurantsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) RestaurantsTableSource *source;

@end
```

And set the tableview to use this:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.source;
self.tableView.delegate = self.source;
```

And then, whenever the data changes, I'd reassign it to `RestaurantsTableSource`:

```
self.source.restaurants = [Database getRestaurants]; // Or something like it
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

However, I don't know if this is the best way to handle such a thing. What's your take/feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you until those lines

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self.source;
self.tableView.delegate = self.source;
```

after those lines, I would prefer to call the datasource to retrieve data.

```
[self.source tableView:self.tableView loadPage:1];
```

and implement this public method in your RestaurantsTableSource class something like this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView loadPage:(NSUInteger)page {
     // Implement your server call or local call and finally reloadData
     [tableView reloadData];
}
```